# Sort object as value with int and text value

Tags: php, sorting, object, int

I have a object and have a problem, this object here $product have this keys ( product_title, product_price, product_stock ) and more, I need to sort after product_title and if my object have this products in I can't sort it right.

```
test product 1
test product 11
test product 111
test product 2
test product 20
test product 3
test product 33
test product 333
```

The right way to sort it its like this:

```
test product 1
test product 2
test product 3
test product 11
test product 33
test product 20
test product 111
test product 333
```

I have tried `sort` and `rsort` without luck.

If it can help, my object looks like this:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (49) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(3) "335"
    ["product_guid"]=>
    string(36) "F0161D03-33EF-6F40-C816-AEDB33640E36"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(3) "189"
    ["brand_guid"]=>
    NULL
    ["product_title"]=>
    string(10) "Fadestativ"
    ["push_date"]=>
    string(19) "2011-01-18 13:02:11"
    ["product_price"]=>
    string(3) "560"
    ["product_price_before"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["on_stock"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["product_weight"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["product_int_number"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product_ext_number"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product_small_info"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product_big_info"]=>
    string(31) "3 benet fad stativ højde 19 cm"
    ["active"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["meta_title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["meta_keyword"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["meta_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product_new"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["indicative_price"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["cost_price"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["domain"]=>
    string(26) "eventhuset.schemecloud.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(32) "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"
    ["resellerid"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["defualt_lang"]=>
    string(2) "dk"
    ["quota"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["account_type"]=>
    string(3) "cms"
    ["busniess_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_street"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_city"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_zipcode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_contry"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_contact_person"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_contact_phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_cvr"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_street"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_city"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_zipcode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_contry"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_contact_person"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_cvr"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["payment_expires"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["next_order_number"]=>
    string(5) "10001"
    ["order_prefix"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#14 (49) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(3) "306"
    ["product_guid"]=>
    string(36) "8119C253-84C7-73AC-4125-DF4B1728A203"
    ["account_id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(3) "189"
    ["brand_guid"]=>
    NULL
    ["product_title"]=>
    string(15) "Kartoffel skål"
    ["push_date"]=>
    string(19) "2011-01-17 13:40:08"
    ["product_price"]=>
    string(3) "680"
    ["product_price_before"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["on_stock"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["product_weight"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["product_int_number"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product_ext_number"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product_small_info"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product_big_info"]=>
    string(31) "Kartoffel skål i rustfri stål"
    ["active"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["meta_title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["meta_keyword"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["meta_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["product_new"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["indicative_price"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["cost_price"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["domain"]=>
    string(26) "eventhuset.schemecloud.com"
    ["password"]=>
    string(32) "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"
    ["resellerid"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["defualt_lang"]=>
    string(2) "dk"
    ["quota"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["account_type"]=>
    string(3) "cms"
    ["busniess_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_street"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_city"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_zipcode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_contry"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_contact_person"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_contact_phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["busniess_cvr"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_street"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_city"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_zipcode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_contry"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_contact_person"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["invoice_cvr"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["payment_expires"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["next_order_number"]=>
    string(5) "10001"
    ["order_prefix"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
```

and I need to sort after

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (49) {
    ["product_title"]=>
    string(10) "Fadestativ"
}
```

Comment: Show your code.  Without that, we can't guess at the structure of the array you're trying to sort...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, assuming that they are objects (which from your description and comments they appear to be), you can use a [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

PHP 5.3+:

```
usort(
    $array, 
    function($a, $b) {
        return strnatcmp($a->title, $b->title);
    }
);
```

PHP <= 5.2:

```
usort(
    $array;
    create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcmp($a->title, $b->title);`)
);
```

Change `->title` to whatever property you want to sort by.  And if you want case insensitivity, use [`strnatcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcasecmp.php) instead of `strnatcmp()`...

Answer (score -1):

Try sort() again but you will have to use a second parameter:

```
sort($array, SORT_STRING);
```